# Passing a variable through passport authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS running on Netlify to do user authentication via OAuth for an external website.  I've gotten it to successfully do the authentication, but I'm utterly stumped on needing to pass through a variable (returnToUrl) that indicates eventual disposition of the request.  My reading says I should set it in the session, and I'm doing that, but then the value isn't available to the callback.

Here's what I've got currently:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const serverless = require('serverless-http');

const AmazonStrategy = require("passport-amazon").Strategy;

const express = require("express");
const session = require('express-session')
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

app.use(session({ 
  secret: "xxxxxxxx" ,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new AmazonStrategy({
  clientID: process.env['AMAZON_CLIENT_ID'],
  clientSecret: process.env['AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET'],
  callbackURL: AUTH_BASE + "/amazon/callback",
  scope: ['profile']
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    let user = profile
    return done(null, user);
  
}
)
);
app.get('/auth/amazon',
   (req,res,next)  => {
     req.session.returnToUrl = req.originalUrl;
     console.log('try amazon auth, req.session is', req.session); // session includes the returnToUrl value
     passport.authenticate('amazon')(req,res,next)
  }
    );

app.get('/auth/amazon/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('amazon', { scope: ['profile', 'postal_code'], failureRedirect: '/login', failureMessage: true}),
    (req, res, next) =>  {
      console.log('req.session is is', req.session); // session is present, minus returnToUrl
        console.log('data received',req.session.returnToUrl); // This returns UNDEFINED
        res.redirect('/auth');
    }
  );

app.get('/auth', async (req, res) => {
    // some stuff removed
    console.log('data received at /auth',req.session.returnToUrl) ; UNDEFINED
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!